# How conda environments can be visible for all users added into jupyterhub?

Tags: conda, jupyterhub, virtual-environment, multiple-users

I am using `jupyterhub` where i have installed `conda` and created `environments` too, from the perspective of the admin. My concern is that i have also added some other users into `jupyterhub` server but those users cannot see any of what i have installed in the `admin` user. How can I do that ?

I want other users that i have added to the server to be able to chose the appropriate `kernel` environment to be able to run the notebooks i will be sending them. (Without asking every user to create every kernel environment and install every package in it...then add it to the kernelspec)

Comment: best to do this when setting up/upgrading the cluster, e.g. by bundling environments into a docker file. see: https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html